# Apagar todas as tabelas de um banco de uma vez

Tags: sql, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Existe uma forma de eu apagar todo um banco de dados de uma única vez? Não é `drop`, é deletar apenas os registros de todas as tabelas pertencentes ao banco de dados.

Comment: usando o DELETE?

Comment: Não tinha reparado que era para todas as tabelas :P

Comment: O delete eu apago tabela por tabela e o que eu quero é em um único comando deletar todas de uma vez, sem dó.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para todas as tabelas, execute:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?'
```

Vale para o SQL Server 2005 e superiores. Pode falhar com constraints habilitadas.

Para excluir tudo com constraints, use:

```
-- desabilitar constraints
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

-- excluir linhas de todas as tabelas
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable "DELETE FROM ?"

-- habilitar constraints
exec sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Pode também ser necessário arrumar as colunas identity. Para isso, use:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "DBCC CHECKIDENT ( '?', RESEED, 0)"
```

[Tirei isso daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156813/1314276) (pra não dizer que não falei de ética).

Comment: Morrison Mende, está dando erro de violação de constraint(FK), mas pelo seu script ele desabilita as FK's, certo? Esse é o erro: Cannot truncate table 'Dominios.TBTipoProcesso' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: @pnet Use a segunda parte do script, por favor.

Comment: Mais uma boa resposta :)

Answer (score 7):

Teria que criar um *script* para fazer o trabalho todo. A forma mais simples de fazer isto é dar um `TRUNCATE` em cada uma das tabelas. Mas isto não funcionará bem se você tiver certas restrições na tabela. Então você teria que desligar todas as restrições antes, o que daria um certo trabalho.

Então provavelmente o mais fácil seria você copiar a estrutura das tabelas para novas tabelas sem os dados, possivelmente em outro banco de dados, algo assim:

```
SELECT * INTO tabela_nova From tabela_existente WHERE 1 = 2;
```

De acordo com [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899881/221800) é possível automatizar a retirada das restrições e usar o `TRUNCATE` assim:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ENABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ?'
GO
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/DeleteAllTables.sql).